# NODE_ENV and Github Actions

Tags: node.js, github-actions, playwright

I'm having a hard time with running E2E tests in a desired environment when I execute the tests in GitHub Actions and I'm thinking this may not work the way I expect but trying to figure it out...

I have a typescript repo that runs [playwright](https://playwright.dev/) E2E tests using one of the following 3 commands from **package.json** in one of three environments (test, staging, and production)

```
"playwright:test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test playwright test ",
"playwright:staging": "cross-env NODE_ENV=staging playwright test ",
"playwright:production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production playwright test "
```

I use **cross-env** npm package of env config and running any of these scripts locally works as I expect against the respective environments

Now, I am trying to set up a GitHub Action that will execute one of these scripts.
I have 3 environments with corresponding secrets for passwords and API keys etc.

I **am able** to run the tests in GitHub actions with the following piece of yaml

```
- name: Run tests
        env:
          TENANT_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.TENANT_PASSWORD}}
          run: npm run playwright:test
```

My issue is I am calling `npm run playwright:test` in the above which is setting the **NODE_ENV** to **test** and all is fine, tests run against the test environment, but I cannot figure out is how to use this same action to trigger the execution in a different env, (other than test).  current thought is maybe something like this

```
- name: Run tests
        env:
          TENANT_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.TENANT_PASSWORD}}
          run: npm run playwright:${{ENVIRONMENT}}
```

but I don't know how I'd set the ${{ENVIRONMENT}} externally...  thinking this through as I type this, maybe its easiest is to define 3 different actions, one per env, and trigger?

Any thoughts are much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use [single dimension matrix](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs#example-using-a-single-dimension-matrix)!

Here is what you can do, but I haven't tested it by myself.

```yaml
env:
  TENANT_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.TENANT_PASSWORD}}

jobs:
  example_matrix:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        env: [test, staging, production]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm run playwright:${{ matrix.env }}
```

Comment: Had not thought of that - definitely a possibility :-)  don't want the tests to run against all environments as the features in 'test'  for instance may not yet be deployed to the other envs and would fail

Comment: ah, in that case, maybe you want to add a "deploy" step before "test" step? and you can use environment with manual_approval.

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#deployment-protection-rules